# Classic ASP class property with inheritance

Tags: inheritance, asp-classic

I'm having a serious brain fart as to why this isn't working for me.  I have two classes

```
class Order

    private Test_1
    private oCustomer

    public property get Test() Test= Test_1 end property
    public property let Test( value ) Test_1 = value end property


  public property get Customer()

    if ( NOT isObject( oCustomer ) ) then

        set oCustomer = new OrderCustomer

    end if

    set Customer = oCustomer

  end property

end class


class OrderCustomer

    private FirstName_1

    public property get FirstName() FirstName = FirstName_1 end property
    public property let FirstName( value ) FirstName_1 = value end property

end class
```

When I call the following code I get the result in the comments

```
set oOrder = new Order

    oOrder.Test = "Hi"
    response.write oOrder.Test()    'writes out "HI"

    oOrder.Customer.FirstName = "Fred"    'does actually set it to this value, I am able to response.write out FirstName_1 after it is set in let
    response.write oOrder.Customer.FirstName() 'writes out nothing

set oOrder = nothing
```

What am I missing here? I was pretty sure I did this on previous projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that every time to access the Customer property it creates a new one

Proposed solution (not tested):

```
  private _Customer
  public property get Customer()
    if _Customer is nothing then
       set _Customer = new OrderCustomer
    end if
    set Customer = _Customer
  end property
```

Comment: I do have this in the code, just didn't put it in my example above.  if ( NOT isObject( oCustomer ) ) then set oCustomer = new OrderCustomer end if set Customer = oCustomer.

Comment: Haha, I updated the code to show that it wasn't recreating itself and noticed i was checking if oCustomer[s] was an object instead of oCustomer. Le sigh...

Answer (score 0):

The property is always returning a new Customer. You should change order to something like

```
class Order

    private m_Customer

    private sub Class_Initialize()
        set m_Customer = new Customer
    end sub

    public property get Customer()

        set Customer = m_Customer

    end property

end class
```

This will create a new customer object when an order is created.

Additionally, what is happening here isn't actually inheritance. Customer is just a property of the Order.

Comment: Haha, I updated the code to show that it wasn't recreating itself and noticed i was checking if oCustomer[s] was an object instead of oCustomer.  Le sigh...

Comment: No worries. The act of writing out the problem in the form of a SO question often leads to the answer.